# Use grep with or

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, filter

How do I search in a textfile with grep for the occurrence of a word or another word?

I want to filter the apache log file for all lines including "bot" or "spider"

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log|grep -i spider
```

shows only the lines including "spider", but how do I add "bot"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use classic regex:

```
grep -i 'spider\|bot'
```

or extended regex (or even perl regex `-P`):

```
grep -Ei 'spider|bot'
```

or multiple literal patterns (faster than a regular expression):

```
grep -Fi -e 'spider' -e 'bot'
```

Comment: +1 for covering multiple bases and also (implicitly) losing the `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep -E 'spider|bot'
```

With the -E option you activate extended regular expression, where you can use `|` for an logical OR.

Besides, instead of invoking another process - cat - you can do this with

```
grep -E 'spider|bot' /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

$ cat /var/log/apache2/access.log|grep -i 'spider\|bot'

The above will do the job.

You can also use egrep

$ cat /var/log/apache2/access.log|egrep -i 'spider|bot'

egrep is extended grep (grep -E). You will not have to use \ before | if you use egrep.

Answer (score -1):

You can use egrep instead:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log|egrep -i 'spider|bot'
```

Comment: “`egrep` is the same as `grep -E`. … Direct invocation as … `egrep` … is deprecated” – man `grep`

Comment: -1 The double pipe `||` means 'or', it's not a pipe at all. Also you might want to fix the [UUCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: The double-pipe ignored, on some platforms grep -E is not available and egrep is the only option.

Comment: the double | was a mistype actually.